# My new Dell XPS 12 ultrabook keeps beeping forever after pressing the power button and doesn't start

Tags: boot, laptop, dell-xps

I've just bought a new [Dell XPS 12 12.5-Inch Convertible 2-in-1 Touchscreen Ultrabook](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-12-9q33/pd). After pressing the power button for the first time it started making beeps without stopping. There's no display and the laptop doesn't start. The only way to stop the beeps is by continuously pressing the power button until it finally shuts down. The beeps have a constant interval between them of about one second. What could the problem be and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

"How do I fix it?" Well, that's easy. It's pretty obviously broken *somehow*, and since it's new, just **take it back to where you bought it for a replacement unit.** If you bought it in a brick-and-mortar store, I'd suggest insisting on testing the new unit before leaving the store.

Generally speaking, beep codes on power-on indicate a problem with low-level hardware. I'm not familiar with the XPS 12 specifically so cannot tell from the particular beep code what the problem likely is in your specific situation, but there are a few things that are usual suspects:

- No CPU installed, or CPU self-test failure (*if* the motherboard is able to detect and report this condition; if not, the system plain won't turn on, period)
- No RAM, incorrectly installed RAM, or damaged RAM
- No graphics adapter detected

Any of these should be a valid reason for a RMA on a brand-new laptop of any kind.

What you definitely **should not do** is try to repair it yourself. Trying to repair it yourself would have been an appropriate course of action if it was a system you'd built yourself, or if it was out of warranty, but not with a completely new computer.

Comment: FYI: There is no POST code for "No CPU" in the PC world, as the POST can't run without the CPU.

Comment: @techie007 I'm pretty sure I've come across that one; it doesn't take a lot of circuitry to detect and report such a problem. Anyway, hopefully clarified now that it's only a possibility and limited to such a situation. Better?

Comment: I thought I had experienced it as well, but never actually found one to prove it. ;)  In the world of "IBM compatible PC" computers though, a CPU is required, as it's the reset of the CPU that causes the POST to start: "The BIOS begins its POST when the CPU is reset." [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test#IBM-compatible_PC_POST).  Anyhow, just info -- your answer is good by me (hence I up-voted it ;) )

Comment: @techie007 Well, considering that with ATX pressing the power button signals the CPU to switch the PSU to a different power state... augh, it was easier before!

Comment: hehehe.. Yeah XT/AT was much easier to comprehend. ;)

Answer (score 1):

When the display doesn't turn on and the computer beeps, it tends to indicate that something is VERY wrong, last time this happened to me it was due to broken hardware, since you say it's new I reccomend returning it or if it's under warranty send it in for servicing.